# Show the following condition holds.

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, definite-integrals

Given that a function $f:\left[a,b\right]\to\mathbb{R}$ such that,$\left|f\left(x\right)-f\left(y\right)\right|\leq\left|x-y\right|\text{ }\forall\text{ }x,y\in\left[a,b\right]$ Then, show that,$\left|\int\limits _{a}^{b}f\left(x\right)dx-\left(b-a\right)f\left(a\right)\right|\leq\frac{1}{2}\left(b-a\right)^{2}$ provided, $f$ is integrable on $\left[a,b\right]$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: $\int_a^bf(x)\,dx - (b-a)f(a) = \int_a^b(f(x)-f(a))\,dx.$

Answer (score -1):

We can write the given integral :-
$\left|\int\limits _{a}^{b}f\left(x\right)-\left(b-a\right)f\left(a\right)\right|=\left|\int\limits _{a}^{b}\left(f\left(x\right)-f\left(a\right)\right)dx\right|\leq\int\limits _{a}^{b}\left|f\left(x\right)-f\left(a\right)\right|dx\leq\int\limits _{a}^{b}\left|x-a\right|dx=\frac{1}{2}\left(b-a\right)^{2}$